# Upgrade to React version 16.10.2 error while using Ant Design Components. Function components cannot be given refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I recently upgraded to `React version 16.10.2`. And facing **errors** while using And Design Components.

I want to use Title from Typography.
Here is what I was doing earlier.

```
import { Typography } from 'antd'
const { Title } = Typography 

<Title level={4}>Hello World</Title>
```

I have an **error** in `console` as follows

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref
>   will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Comment: This is a work around for legacy components... https://github.com/atomiks/tippy.js-react#component-children

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed in antd@3.23.6: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/pull/19074